# save value array

Tags: php

Boas a todos, Preciso de ajuda numa duvida que estou a ter neste momento. Tenho o seguinte array:

```
Array
(
    [regista] => stdClass Object
        (
            [info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [nome] => 2222
                    [tipo] => N
                    [classe] => SI
                

            [infoResult] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [codResultOper] => 2001
                    [msgResultOper] => nome registado com sucesso :123456789
                )

        )

)
```

E pretendia guardar apenas istodo array [msgResultOper] => nome registado com sucesso:123456789

ja tentei o seguinte:

```
print_r($retorno = (array) $client->nome($param));
    $regista= (array) $retorno["regista"];
     $infoResult= (array) $retorno["infoResult"];

      $ReturnMessage = $infoResult["msgResultOper"];


      print_r($ReturnMessage);
```

Mas com isto devolve sempre o erro:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: codResultOper in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\comunicar.php on line 74.
```

o que estou a fazer errado? como posso guardar esse valor?

Comment: `codResultOper` não está sendo usado nesse código que postou em "ja tentei o seguinte:". Em "Tenho o seguinte array:", supondo que você tenha dado um print_r em uma variável fictícia chamada $dados, seria só usar `$dados['regista']->infoResult->msgResultOper;`.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro significa que o PHP não conseguiu encontrar o índice `codResultOper` no seu código.

Isso aconteceu porque você está tentando acessar um `objeto` como se fosse um `array`.

Repare na estrutura que você descreveu, onde `regista`, `info` e `infoResult` são

> stdClass Object

dentro de um

> Array

sendo assim, para acessar `Array > regista > infoResult > msgResultOper` você precisa fazer um `cast`:

```
$obj = (object) $array;
```

isso vai converter o array para objeto e simplificar o acesso:

```
$obj->regista->infoResult->msgResultOper;
```

Veja mais sobre `cast` clicando [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869147/19146483).

O código completo ficou assim:

```
<?php
    //replicando o array exemplificado
    $array = [
        'regista' => (object) 
        [
            'info' => (object) [
                'nome' => 222, 'tipo' => 'N', 'classe' => 'SI'
            ], 
            'infoResult' => (object) [
                'codResultOper' => 2001, 'msgResultOper' => 'nome registrado com sucesso: 123456789'
            ]
        ]
    ];    
    //cast array -> object
    $obj = (object) $array;
    //acessando 'codResultOper' e armazenando na variável
    $returnMessage = $obj->regista->infoResult->msgResultOper;
    //mosrtando o resultado
    print_r($returnMessage);


?>
```